# Logic need to checked in Unit test cases method

Tags: unit-testing, mstest

I have a GET method for webAPI which returns say hundred Products list. What logic should one need to check to diagnose the test as pass or fail?

Should I check for count>0 or anything else?

Ideally I should not check for product count as it may change (count==100).

Comment: Broke the sentences into paragraphs and added question marks wherever applicable.

Clearly formatted questions get more attention.

Comment: Include relevant code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out these useful links on unit testing with async web requests:

- https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/85321/unit-testing-http-requests
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh404088.aspx
- https://codeutopia.net/blog/2015/01/30/how-to-unit-test-nodejs-http-requests/
- http://www.jeremyg.net/entry/unit-testing-a-fetch-api-service-in-aurelia
- http://lazamar.github.io/testing-http-requests-with-jasmine/
- [Why should I mock HTTP requests inside unit tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24195835/why-should-i-mock-http-requests-inside-unit-tests)

Suppose your client component has a variable *count* that it initialized to 0. Then you fire some web request, and it responds with data like this:

```
{
  response: 500
}
```

where response can have any whole number value. Then count gets set to the value of response.

The basic gist of this unit test would be to mock the actual calling to the server (instead of making the api call and return the response, just return a hardcoded object). Then assert that the "count" variable is as you would expect it to be from this predefined response. You can then set up multiple cases (ie multiple tests) for each possible type of response that can be returned. Good luck!